# Angular extending class with nested not exported class

Tags: angular, inheritance, internal

Minimizing structure of my problem we have:

lib.module.ts (Module of library - wished to be unchanged)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   InternalComponent,
   ExternalComponent
  ],
  exports: [
   ExternalComponent
  ]
})
export class LibModule {}
```

external.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'external',
    template: '<internal></internal> We are in external',
    styles: ['']
})
export class ExternalComponent{}
```

internal.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'internal',
    template: 'This is internal',
    styles: ['']
})
export class InternalComponent{}
```

So my duty is to extend `ExternalComponent`. As far as I know we inherit only logic from typescript. Css and html has to be managed independently, in my case - copied and a little bit modified. However how can I copy html of `ExternalComponent` while `InternalComponent` isn't exported from `LibModule`? 

Let's say `ExternalExtendComponent` is declared in `AppModule`. In `AppModule` I cannot import `InternalComponent`. So I cannot have template in ExternalExtendComponent with tag `<internal>`. Any idea of going through that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution might be writing my own module and don't use library's one.
It would look like this:
app.module.ts

```
import {InternalComponent,ExternalComponent} from 'myLib'; #myLib is in node_modules
import {TreeSelectExtComponent} from './tree-select-ext/tree-select-ext.component';

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
           InternalComponent,
           ExternalComponent,
           ExternalExtComponent
          ]
        })
        export class AppModule{}
```

Important thing is that we cannot import LibModule anywhere in the project couse of double declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to extend `ExternalComponent` actually, you can simply use `external` tag in your `ExternalExtendComponent` html file. This will copy the html of `external` inside it.
This will also render `internal` component inside `extended-external` without exporting it from `LibModule`

See this small [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohbgov)

EDIT :

To override external component, create a template reference `(#ext)` against `external` tag in `extended-external-comp`.

To inject styles, you can use `Renderer2`

Sample code

```
  @ViewChild('ext') ext : ElementRef

  constructor(private renderer : Renderer2 ) {
  }

  addStyles() {
    let animationState;
    let pEl = this.ext.nativeElement.querySelector('p')
    this.renderer.setStyle(pEl.nativeElement, '@ext', animationState);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Though important point of my problem is that I want to slightly change the html of ExternalComponent. For example instead of `<p>external works!</p>` I'd like to place `<p [@ext]="animationState">external works!</p>` to have angular animation working. Is that somehow possible without editing external.component.html that is in library?

Comment: So you are not actually extending, but overriding external component. Thats a tedious task, but I think which is still doable. You have to dig inside the dom of external component and remove/add elements thereafter.

Comment: If that is the only thing that you want to override inside external component, then you can make use of `Renderer2` to add css.

Comment: That solves the problem in the comment. Also as you said it might be problematic in more complicated example, so I will accept the solution with new module. Thought I didn't know that renderer can also sets div's trigger name. Thanks :)